# Adding CSS3 animation to elements created with HTML string method in pure JavaScript ( No Library)

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, transition

I am struggling to create a fade in effect using vanilla JavaScript. Adding a className property works for the elements created using document.createElement method but doesn't not seem to work using `var elem = "<li> List Item </li>"` method. I have ul with id list in html and I am creating a list item using html string method. I am using list.innerHTML = elem to append list item to the list and then trying to add a class "fade-in" on list item. I have used setTimeout function to delay the animation but it still doesn't work. Please refer to the code below.

```js
var list = document.getElementById("list");

var li = "<li> This is a list item</li>";
list.innerHTML = li;
li.className = "fade-in";
// setTimeout(function(){
//   li.className = "fade-in";
// },5);
```

```css
#list {
  opacity: 0;
}

.fade-in {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #84ac47;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ul id="list"></ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a css animation

```
@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.fade-in{
    animation: fadeIn .25s forwards;
}
```

And change your `li` string to be `<li class="fade-in">...</li>`. That way the class will be on the element when you use innerHTML and the animation will take care of the opacity change.

**Updated Explanation:**

So you are adding the `li` element to the DOM using innerHTML. When that element is added to the DOM it has the class `fade-in`.

We create a css animation using [`@keyframes` rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) and we arbitrarily  name our animation `fadeIn`. Within the `@keyframes` rule we specify what we want our animation to do when applied to an element. We say we want to start at `opacity: 0` and go to `opacity: 1`.

We use the animation by specifying the `animation` property on the `.fade-in` class. We called our animation `fadeIn` so by setting the animation property on the `.fade-in` class we are saying we want all elements with `.fade-in` to complete the `fadeIn` animation in `.25s` and set the [animation-fill-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) property to `forwards` which means it will keep the final animation styles when the animation is done.

Comment: Would you mind explaining a little whats happening here in this code?

Answer (score 1):

First up, you are attempting to do DOM manipulation on a string with `li.className=`. Thie list item is not a DOM element yet. It will be once you set the inner HTML

Also you have opacity 0 on the `ul` that will override child elements.

```js
var list = document.getElementById("list");

var li = "<li class='fade-in'> This is a list item</li>";
//li.className = "fade-in"; -- Can't set className on a string
list.innerHTML = li;
console.log(list);
// setTimeout(function(){
//   li.className = "fade-in";
// },5);
```

```css
#list>li { /*Set opacity on this list itmes, not the list*/
  opacity: 0;
}

#list .fade-in { /*Use a selector that is atleast as specific as the above.*/
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #84ac47;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <ul id="list">
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**Option 2**

If you want to work with DOM elements only, you can do the following.

```js
var list = document.getElementById("list");

var li = document.createElement('li'); //Now we have a dom element
li.innerHTML = "This is a list item";
list.appendChild(li);
console.log(list);
 setTimeout(function(){
   li.className = "fade-in";
 },5);
```

```css
#list>li { /*Set opacity on this list itmes, not the list*/
  opacity: 0;
}

#list .fade-in { /*Use a selector that is atleast as specific as the above.*/
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 2s;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #84ac47;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <ul id="list">
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Keep in mind, repeated DOM manipulations can use a lot of resources, so injecting strings is sometimes considered a better practice.

Comment: I tried setting opacity of li element as well and setting class after I append li to list and it still didn't work. You can try yourself.

Comment: The variable `li` is **never** a DOM element in this context. It is a string. That string is then used to replace the existing HTML in the DOM for the UL. Are you saying my solution does not work?

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/g9g6sxLe/1/ for a difference between using string and DOM

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<ul id="div1">
<li id="p1">This is a paragraph.</li>
<li id="p2">This is another paragraph.</li>
</ul>
<style>
#list>li { /*Set opacity on this list itmes, not the list*/
  opacity: 0;
}

#list .fade-in { /*Use a selector that is atleast as specific as the above.*/
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #84ac47;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 5px;
}
</style>
<script>
window.onload = function(e){ 
var para = document.createElement("li");
var node = document.createTextNode("This is new.");
para.appendChild(node);
para.className = "fade-in";
var element = document.getElementById("div1");
element.appendChild(para);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

i edit it. hope helpful

Comment: Item is being created and there is no issue in creating element this way. Just can't figure out how to add animations.

Comment: Your mean is how to add animations when window.onload or on click.